# The destination phone number has been blocked by Verify Geo-Permissions. NZ is blocked for key xxx

Tags: twilio

currently, I am facing an issue with Verify Geo Permissions. I have checked the related docs and reached my admin, and he can confirm that all Verify Geo-Permissions for New Zealand have been checked to be available on the panel (SMS and Voice Channel). Can anyone let me know what can be the other reasons for this error message to be given?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are now separate geo permissions specifically for Verify, more details here:

Verify Geo Permissions available in console now.
https://www.twilio.com/changelog/verify-geopermissions-available-in-console-now

Did you use these?

Answer (score 0):

Because the link provided is dead, I am providing a way to overcome this problem.

1. You can access and enable the country you are targeting: https://console.twilio.com/us1/develop/verify/settings/geopermissions
2. You can access to view the documentation:
   a) https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/preventing-toll-fraud/verify-geo-permissions b) https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/5054044369179-Error-60605-Verification-delivery-attempt-blocked
3. You can view your logs from your Sidebar. Select monitor and log section. There are several clues that you can follow there.